# Multiprocessing Pool hangs/crashes on first batch

Tags: pytorch, multiprocessing

I'm trying to train 50 small models on 5 cpus. Defining the dataloader before the pool operation seems to fail but only on the first set of runs. See code below:

```
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from torch.multiprocessing import Pool

import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.nn as nn
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from functools import partial

def runner(itera,train_loader):
    print(f'Start {itera}')

    loss_func = nn.MSELoss()
    netSGD = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784,10))
    sgd = torch.optim.SGD(netSGD.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
    
    losses = {"sgd":[],}
    for epoch in range(10):
        netSGD.train()
        for x,y in train_loader:
            x = x.view(-1,784)
            y = F.one_hot(y, num_classes=10)

            sgd.zero_grad()
            out = netSGD(x)
            loss = loss_func(out, y.float())
            loss.backward()
            sgd.step()
            
            losses['sgd'].append(loss.item())
    print(f'done {itera}')
    return losses
try:
    pool = Pool(5)

    data_dir = "./data/mnist/"
    apply_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(
        data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=apply_transform
    )
    train_loader = DataLoader(
        train_dataset,
        batch_size=60000,
        shuffle=False,
        num_workers=0,
    )

    all_res = []
    vals = pool.map(
        func=partial(
            runner,
            train_loader=train_loader,
        ),
        iterable=range(10),
    )
    for result in vals:
        all_res.append(result)

finally:
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Done all')
```

What happens is it fails on the first 5 runs but the last 5 run to completion.
The output to this that I get is something like:

```
Start 0Start 1Start 3Start 4Start 2




Start 5
Start 6
Start 7
Start 8
Start 9
done 6
done 7
done 9
done 5
done 8
```

And the program hangs.

However if i load the data and instantiate the dataloader within the runner function, the program runs as intended and the output looks like

```
Start 1Start 0Start 2

Start 3
Start 4

done 4
Start 5
done 3
Start 6
done 1
done 2
done 0
Start 7
Start 9Start 8

done 5
done 9
done 7
done 6
done 8
Done all
```

ie they all run as intended.

Any clue why the first round crashes when i instantiate the dataloader **before** the runner function and pass it as an argument? I think it isn't very memory or time efficient having to load the data within the runner function.

My environment: python 3.9.5, torch 1.4.0, torchvision 0.5.0, running on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

Comment: I have a similar issue and I can't figure it out. One conjecture is that there is no `.share_memory()` method for Dataloader classes (but there is for torch.Tensor and torch.NN classes and calling it seems to be required if they are instantiated before multiprocessing.